# Modify .htaccess to change query parameter to iOS deep-link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, deep-linking

I am trying to do the following:

user visits URL with query parameter:
http://www.example.com/?invite=1234

I then want them to be deep linked into the app on their iOS device, so they go to:
app_name://1234

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in my .htaccess file?

Comment: Great question! Did you ever manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the url is:

```
http://www.example.com/invite/1234/
```

you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^invite/(.*)/$    app_name://$1    [NC,L]
```

---

You may want to read [introduction-to-url-rewriting](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, I tried running that [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be), and it doesn't seem to work. Instead, the output is still the same as the input URL.